# Connect to ETapestry's API via .Net 4 Web Services (Service Reference, not Web Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

Connecting to eTapestry with .Net 4's API gets me the exception:

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`
>   `Parameter name: name`

Terribly unuseful as `name` is not a parameter in my code, or the code I can step into, anywhere.

Code to connect:

```
var client = new ETap.MessagingServiceClient();
client.login(username, password);
var funds = client.getFunds(false);
```

The `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` oddly enough is thrown on the final line, not when logging in - that call succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1) The eTapestry API uses and requires cookies, which can be unusual to come across in .Net web service usage. The obscure:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: name`
```

Is being thrown in the layer that handles cookie authentication (or rather, fails to). The solution is simple - add `allowCookies="true"` to your binding:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ETap"
            allowCookies="true"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://bos.etapestry.com/v2messaging/service?WSDL"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ETap"
        contract="ETap.MessagingService" name="ETap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note also that I've increased the `maxReceivedMessageSize` to 1mb (1048576), since the default 65536 can be quite small, and it's typical for eTapestry queries to overrun such a small size.

2) ETapestry's documentation states they can move your data store at any time, and if they do, your login will succeed but return the name of the new endpoint you should use. Their sample code, in PHP, simply uses an `if` statement to do the whole login process over again, but they don't explain whether there's any guarantee this couldn't happen repeatedly. For example, you might attempt to login to BOS, find you've been directed to SNA, login there, and find you've been directed another place - after all there's time between your logins and it's not clear what the timeline is between eTapestry moves. So we'll use a while loop:

```
var client = new ETap.MessagingServiceClient();
string sessionEndpoint = client.login(username, password);

int attempts = 0;
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionEndpoint))
{
    if (attempts++ > 10)
        throw new Exception("ETapestry failed to provide a final endpoint.");

    client = new ETap.MessagingServiceClient("ETap", sessionEndpoint);
    sessionEndpoint = client.login(username, password);
}
```

With a max on the loop to protect us from an external system leading us into an infinite loop.

That was enough to get method calls to their API to succeed.